# Скачивание файла через urllib

Tags: python, urllib

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как скачать файл средствами python (urllib) доступный по http и положить его рядом со скриптом?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

urllib -> urlopen - открывает файл по данной ему ссылке для чтения, далее можете его просто считать read(), открыть файл для бинарной записи, и записать в него то что прочитали по http. Пример скачивания эмблемки:

```
import urllib
logo = urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png").read()
f = open("logo3w.png", "wb")
f.write(logo)
f.close()
```

Также есть urllib.urlretrieve(url, [filname,[...]]) - по моему его предназначение именно для скачивания.

```
import urllib
destination = 'logo3w.png'
url = 'http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'
urllib.urlretrieve(url, destination)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

url = 'http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg?p=rb/CollaredLorys_ROW927887560.jpg'
destination = url.rsplit('/',1)[1]
urlretrieve(url, destination)
```

Чтобы сохранить читаемые русские имена, можно использовать более сложный способ вычисления имени файла [`url2filename()`](https://gist.github.com/zed/c2168b9c52b032b5fb7d):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import posixpath
try:
    from urlparse import urlsplit
    from urllib import unquote
except ImportError: # Python 3
    from urllib.parse import urlsplit, unquote

def url2filename(url):
    """Return basename corresponding to url.

    >>> print(url2filename('http://example.com/path/to/file%C3%80?opt=1'))
    fileÀ
    >>> print(url2filename('http://example.com/slash%2fname')) # '/' in name
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    ValueError
    """
    urlpath = urlsplit(url).path
    basename = posixpath.basename(unquote(urlpath))
    if (os.path.basename(basename) != basename or
        unquote(posixpath.basename(urlpath)) != basename):
        raise ValueError  # reject '%2f' or 'dir%5Cbasename.ext' on Windows
    return basename
```

Пример:

```
local_filename, headers = urlretieve(url, url2filename(url))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
urllib.urlrertieve(url, filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

`destination = url.rsplit('/',1)[1]` - Здесь один момент не учтен, если `url` заканчивается на `/` то `destination` это пустая строка.
Можно лимит поставить 2 и проверять длину. Пример:

```
destination = url.rsplit('/',1)[2]
if len(destination) == 0:
    destination = url.rsplit('/',1)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу для версии python3, будет так:

```
import urllib.request
logo = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.marseille-tourisme.com/fileadmin/user_upload/plan_mars2013.jpg").read()
f = open("plan_mars2013.jpg", "wb")
f.write(logo)
f.close()
```

Comment: Посмотрите на [ответ с urlretrieve()](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/60965/23044)

Answer (score -1):

ответ в две строки)

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://откуда_качаем.ком', './ложим_в_текущаю_папку')
```