# Скачивание картинки по url. Как проверить ,что она там есть ? Нужно как то по байтам или еще как?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests
url_img = 'https://catalog.mann-filter.com/media/spin/C_15_893/data/spinpict/001.jpg'
r = requests.get(url_img)

if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    out = open('d:/1.jpg', "wb")
    out.write(r.content)
    out.close()
```

r = requests.get(url_img)
    if r.content ....:

```
# if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok  - не пишите
```

Нужно скачать картинку по `url` , но как проверить ,что она там есть ? Нужно как то по байтам или еще как?

Comment: По каким байтам, если байтом нет? Чем вас код ответа не устраивает?

Comment: если путь не верный , то файл на диске пустой , картинка черного цвета или как там  может по полю content = {bytes} b''

Comment: Если файла нет, то его нет. Если у вас нет 500 рублей в кармане, это не значит, что вместо них у вас там чёрная бумажка лежит.

Comment: я не вижу куда здесь можно файл прикрепить, но если у вас нет другого ответа , то спасибо

Comment: Файл которого нет хотите прикрепить? :)

Comment: который сохраняется, с черным фоном

Comment: Все нормальные серверы при отсутствии запрошенного файла возвращают ошибку с кодом 404

Comment: у кого, что сохранит и какой код приходит?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Скачивание файла через urllib](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/60925/23044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такая заглушка сработала:

```
if len(r.text) > 10:
if len(response.content) != 0:    - так лучше!
```

Comment: есть у кого способ надежней?

Comment: Поведение сервера не соответствует стандарту протокола HTTP, поэтому работа с ним в принципе не может быть надёжной. Нет никакой гарантии, что завтра он не начнёт просто разрывать tcp-соединение или наоборот не начнёт отправлять в него содержимое /dev/urandom вместо выдачи 404-й ошибки.

Answer (score 4):

Если сервер возвращает какое-то случайное содержимое и 200 HTTP статус даже если нет картинки, то можно проверить, что скачанный файл является картинкой, используя [`imghdr` модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html#imghdr.what):

```
import imghdr
from pathlib import Path
import requests  # $ pip install requests

img_path = Path(r'D:\images\1.jpg')
r = requests.get(url)
if r.ok:
    img_path.write_bytes(r.content)  
    if imghdr.what(img_path) == 'jpeg':
        print('выглядит как JPEG картинка')
```

Можно не сохраняя на диск, попробовать распознать картинку:

```
if imghdr.what(None, h=r.content) == 'jpeg':
    print('выглядит как JPEG картинка')
```

Comment: Может стоит еще об [`im.validate()`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.verify) из PIL упомянуть?

Comment: @MaxU вы думаете могла случайно или намеренно быть испорчена картинка? Тогда ожидаемый хэш (sha256) или вообще gpg подпись проверять, что файл ожидаемый дошёл. Если не рассматривать зловредные изменения, то окончательный тест — просто использовать картинку по назначению (LBYL vs. EAFP).

Comment: 1 зачем скачивать , а после проверять , то чего нет.  2 вы хоть пробуете свой код, прежде чем отвечать

Comment: @user284883 1- мы скачиваем только если сервер говорит что *что-то* есть (`if r.ok` часть) 2- если не указано обратного, то считайте что весь код оттестирован в моих ответах. Код определяет  *что-то* похожее на jpeg картинку передано или нет (imghdr.what() часть).

Answer (score 0):

Вообще для скачивания изображения и сохранения его в файл есть готовое решение:

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
urlretrieve(url, file_path)
```

При отсутствии картинки, если сервер вернет 404, функция `urlretrieve` кидает исключение `HTTPError`

Comment: попробуйте сами по этому пути сохранить своим способом

Comment: да, сохранить по абсолютному пути не выходит

Comment: @Денис: что значит "не выходит"? Вы хотите, чтобы вложенные директории автоматически создавались бы? Тогда можно так: `file_path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)` перед `urlretrieve()`, если `file_path` это `pathlib.Path` иначе можно обернуть.

Comment: @jfs, нет, проблема в том, что если указать file_path='d:/1.jpg', то код вывалевается с `permission denied`

Comment: как это к вопросу относятся? вы думаете, что другие способы сохранения такие как open() не вернут ту же ошибку?

Comment: @jfs, ТС так сделал, мб у него сработало.

Comment: @Денис urlretrieve() использует ту же open() внутри. Ну и конечно само сообщение об ошибке подсказывает что внешняя причина  вероятно ответственна.

Comment: @Денис, чтобы победить `permission denied` можно скрипт как админ запускать